# Reservation / register module for D7

Tags: 7, webforms, bookings

I need a simple reservation module for my D7 restaurant site.

What I need in the form is:

1. Customer information fields (Name, email, contact number, address, etc)
2. Number of tables to be reserved by that customer
3. Upon submission of reservation will lead to another link (I will write codes to link to payment gateway)

Admin are able to configure:

1. Price per table (Eg: USD 100 per table)
2. Total number of tables available to reserve (Eg: 100 tables)
3. Closing date for reservation, so that customer can't reserve after the closing date

Admin able to see:

1. Report of reservation
2. Details such as customer name, number of tables reserves, etc

I had tried using [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform), but I can't do the following:

1. Reservation close on particular date
2. Limit number of tables so that overall tables reserved will not exceed 100

Is there any reservation or registration module that I can use?

Or is there any method I can modify my webform to suit the requirement?

Comment: there are numerous reservation modules out there - most designed for hotels, but if you can get past the terminology they should work - a simple search should reveal what you need.

Comment: Have you used Rules module in above method?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the Drupal [Restaurant Distribution](https://www.drupal.org/project/restaurant) is what you need, and if not it should at least give you some ideas.

It contains a number of modules, including on for reservations which I assume will do all you need, and more.

https://www.drupal.org/project/restaurant

From the feature list:

> **Reservation System** - Manage your reservations easily from one
>   dashboard. View all reservations for today, this week or this month.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some modules that might be worth further exploring (quotes are from their project pages):

- [Availability Calendars](https://www.drupal.org/project/availability_calendars) (D6 or D7).

  > ... allows you to add an availability calendar to entities. Example use cases are tourist accommodation, e.g. bed and breakfast, holiday homes or self catered apartments, and car or motor bike rental.
  >
  > An availability calendar shows your customers at what dates your accommodation is still available and at what dates it is already booked.
- [Simple Reservation](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_reservation/) (D6 or D7).

  > ... provides a simple and easy way to reserve items which can be created by the administrator. Examples for it's usage can be hotel rooms, boats, cars, airplanes, basically anything you can think of which can be reserved by one individual.
  >
  > The module provides the possibility to create reservations for other users (dependend on the permissions), and provides also restrictions in the maximum number of reservations a user can make and a maximum time a reservation can be made in advance.
  >
  > There is NO support for payment, booking and what ever one could imagine beyond the pure and simple reservation, and it is also NOT intended to create more than this simple functionality.